# How to update expired identities on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

My certificates were expired a few days ago. I renew them on developer.apple.com:

[image]

In Xcode, I tried:

- click the refresh button
- remove my Apple ID and re-add it

Xcode still shows *expired*:

[image]

How can I refresh the signing identities under Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Apple ID > View Details...?

Comment: Have you tried deleting them in Keychain Access, and refreshing in Xcode afterwards?

Comment: It seems to me it takes a while for Xcode to fetch the new identities. After a few hours, Xcode loads the new identities successfully.